# Failed to run init with error: jffs2: compression type 0x06 not available

Tags: linux, filesystems, configuration, compression

I am working on an embedded Linux system (5.10.24), and I am using jffs2 as the rootfs.
Now I changed the kernel configuration of jffs2 as follows,

```
# CONFIG_JFFS2_FS_WBUF_VERIFY is not set
# CONFIG_JFFS2_SUMMARY is not set
# CONFIG_JFFS2_FS_XATTR is not set
CONFIG_JFFS2_COMPRESSION_OPTIONS=y
# CONFIG_JFFS2_ZLIB is not set
CONFIG_JFFS2_LZO=y
# CONFIG_JFFS2_RTIME is not set
# CONFIG_JFFS2_RUBIN is not set
# CONFIG_JFFS2_CMODE_NONE is not set
# CONFIG_JFFS2_CMODE_PRIORITY is not set
# CONFIG_JFFS2_CMODE_SIZE is not set
CONFIG_JFFS2_CMODE_FAVOURLZO=y
```

And used `mkfs.jffs2 -e 0x8000 -p -l -n -X lzo` to build jffs2 image.

After system booted up, it reported following error.

```
Run /init as init process
jffs2: compression type 0x06 not available
jffs2: Error: jffs2_decompress returned -5
Kernel panic - not syncing: Requested init /init failed (error -5).
```

I am puzzled!

From the error message, it seemed that jffs2 image is compressed by ZLIB, but I specified `-X lzo` to the `mkfs.jffs2`.

So how to make system boot with jffs2 system using LZO?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the root cause.

This is from the building of rootfs image, which is using ZLIB by default. To make LZO work, there needs 2 things.

1. Enable `CONFIG_JFFS2_LZO=y` in kernel configuration, other compression configurations can be disabled.
2. Run mkfs.jffs2 with `-X lzo -x zlib -x rtime`, which means enable LZO compressor, and disable ZLIB and RTIME compressors.

With above, the rootfs image is compressed with LZO, and it can be booted up with kernel enabled LZO.